# Extract double from a string

Tags: java, string

From the following string:

```
radius: -0.118211 zone
```

how can I extract the number in double format.

Comment: If you want more general answers, handling input other than the exact example you provide here, you should specify in what ways input can vary.

Comment: When you get the answer you're looking for, please accept that answer :-) Thanks!

Comment: This regEx extracts doubles `(-)?(([^\\d])(0)|[1-9][0-9]*)(.)([0-9]+)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
String tmpstr = "radius: -0.118211 zone";
String asd[] = tmpstr.split(" ");
double dbl = Double.parseDouble(asd[1]);
System.out.println(dbl);
```

Comment: `Double.parseDouble` returns `double`, so no need for casting

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Okay, thank you - I read the documentation now, and I realise parseDouble returns the primitive type (I thought it returned an instance of the `Double` class). Now updated my code.

Comment: even if it returned `Double`, you can do `double d = new Double(3);` since Java 5

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
String[] srt = "radius: -0.118211 zone".split(" ");
Double.parseDouble(srt[1]);
```

You should add error checking to avoid out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 3):

```
String stringToStrip="radius: -0.118211 zone";
String stripedValue = (stringToStrip.replaceAll("[\\s+a-zA-Z :]",""));
double dbl = Double.parseDouble(stripedValue);
System.out.println(dbl);
```

Or one liner just for fun and is definitely bad  practice due to bad readiblity

```
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("radius: -0.118211 zone".replaceAll("[\\s+a-zA-Z :]","")));
```

Comment: I understand you're trying to generalize here. However, that can be difficult, considering we don't know the specifications of input. If a digit is appended to the end of the input ("...zone1"), this regex would fail.

Answer (score 2):

```
String result="";
String str= "radius: -0.118211 zone";
String regex ="(-0.)+([0-9]+)";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( regex ).matcher( str);
while (matcher.find( ))
{
result = matcher.group();  
System.out.println("number="+result);                 
}
```

Comment: Please use the regex "[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?" (from http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
String foo = "radius: -0.118211 zone";

String [] result = foo.split(" ");

Double d = Double.valueOf(result[1]);
System.out.println(d);
```

Would this work for you?